# SPARQL select based on the content of the subject

Tags: select, sparql, rdf

I'm new to SPARQL, and I am trying to select a property based on the **content** of the subject. For example, using the RDF data below, I want to return the result containing "var2_1":

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/fred/domain.owl#var0">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/fred/domain.owl#var2_0"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/fred/domain.owl#var1">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/fred/domain.owl#var2_1"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

This is the query I am writing, but it returns nothing, and I can't seem to find a way to specify that the subject should contain "var1":

```
SELECT ?t 
WHERE {
   ?s rdf:type ?t
   FILTER regex(?s, "var1")
}
```

I would appreciate help on the right way to do this.

Comment: resources are identified by URI, and you know the URI, so why do you want to use a REGEX? Do you have a particular use case in mind? I mean, there are some rare cases in which you don't know the full URI, but whenever you know it in advance, it's the better way to follow the answer below. Moreover, it's much more efficient for the SPARQL engine as it can use some database index.

Comment: Just for your future work with RDF and SPARQL. It helps a lot if you look at your data in Turtle syntax which is close to SPARQL query syntax

Comment: Great, thanks AKSW, I'm going to check out Turtle!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subject is not a string literal value, but an IRI: `http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/fred/domain.owl#var1`. To match this, you should not be using a regular expression, but instead use the actual IRI itself:

```
SELECT ?t 
WHERE {
  ?s rdf:type ?t
  FILTER(?s =  <http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/fred/domain.owl#var1>)
}
```

or more succinct:

```
SELECT ?t 
WHERE {
   <http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/fred/domain.owl#var1> rdf:type ?t
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeen, that helps a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The other answer has already pointed out that your `?s` is a URI, and should be matched directly instead of using a regular expression. In addition, it is worth keeping in mind that matching specific URIs becomes much simpler if you have the right prefixes defined. If we define a prefix for the file's URI, then the actual query pattern becomes much simpler:

```
PREFIX fred: <http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/fred/domain.owl#>
SELECT ?t 
WHERE {
   fred:var1 rdf:type ?t
}
```

The query can become even simpler: `rdf:type` has a built-in abbreviation “`a`”, and the `WHERE` keyword is optional:

```
PREFIX fred: <http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/fred/domain.owl#>
SELECT ?t {
   fred:var1 a ?t
}
```

Finally, if you *really* want to use a regular expression to match the URI, you can do that by converting the URI to a string using `str`:

```
SELECT ?t {
   ?s a ?t
   FILTER regex(str(?s), "var1")
}
```

But compared to the other options, this will be extremely slow on larger datasets.

Finally finally, to support AKSW's comment, here is the file converted from RDF/XML to Turtle:

```
PREFIX fred: <http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/fred/domain.owl#>

fred:var0 a fred:var2_0.
fred:var1 a fred:var2_1.
```